# ng build changes < character to lt in jsp pages

Tags: angular, jsp

I have an index.jsp page in my src, with the below line

```
<html>
<body>

<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*" %>

</body></html>
```

But after doing an ng build, the dist folder contains the same jsp page as below.

```
<html>
<body>
&lt;%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*" %&gt;
</body></html>
```

Any idea as to why < gets replaced by lt and > by gt? Any options to override this?

Regards,
Ganesh.

Comment: Look at https://angular.io/guide/security  For security reasons, Angular replaces unsafe characters with safe values.  I add my JSP code after compiling the Angular code.  I take the Angular code out of the index.html file and put it into the index.jsp file in my web server.

Comment: sure thanks a lot @rickz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at
https://angular.io/guide/security
For security reasons, Angular replaces unsafe characters with safe values. Personally, I add my JSP code after compiling the Angular code. I take the Angular code out of the index.html file and put it into the index.jsp file in my web server. You should also know about HTML entities. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Angular 14 and managed to fix it by enclosing the jsp code section in a comment tag like below.

index.jsp

```
<!-- //Prevents Ivy from messing up this section
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%
  String json = " ";
  if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
      String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
      json += "'" + paramName + "':'" + paramValue + "',";
    }
    json = "{" + json.replaceAll("(?i)<(/?script[^>]*)>", "").replaceFirst(".$","") + "}";
  }
%>
-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body id="dataSection" data="<%= json %>">
    <app></app>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, from a component you can access this data by using the code below.

```
//app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    const dataSection = document.getElementById('dataSection');
    const attrs = dataSection.attributes;
    
    const data = attrs['data'].value.replace(/'/g,'"');
    const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('DATA:', parsed);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.